# show/search for active style in chrome dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

At the moment im inspecting lots of buttons and icons that are styled by a framework but often overwritten with custom styles in different ways.

The dev tools do show the hierachy but its very difficult to find the current active value for an attribute if its not overwritten.

Is there a way to search for a style (e.g. search for "font-size" and i get the active result or is there a way to filter the "Styles" tab to only show active values and remove the crossed out values + greyish elements that apply the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tab "Computed" is what you looking for.

Comment: yes it is, wow i somehow didnt see it on ubuntu while its kind of clearly visible on mac, i guess ill have to reorder things...